# I have a subprocess error in Xcode logs at my app launch

Tags: python, ios, kivy, subprocess, zbar

I have a subprocess error in Xcode logs at my app launch

i have installed pyzbar with : toolchain pip install pyzbar

i have build zbar with : toolchain build libzbar

MY FULL LOGS :

```
2024-02-05 10:13:29.313314+0100 MyApp[1218:20214] [SceneConfiguration] Info.plist contained no UIScene configuration dictionary (looking for configuration named "(no name)")
2024-02-05 10:13:29.313657+0100 MyApp[1218:20214] [SceneConfiguration] Info.plist contained no UIScene configuration dictionary (looking for configuration named "(no name)")
2024-02-05 10:13:29.516965+0100 MyApp[1218:20214] Available orientation: KIVY_ORIENTATION=LandscapeLeft LandscapeRight Portrait PortraitUpsideDown
2024-02-05 10:13:29.517238+0100 MyApp[1218:20214] Initializing python
<string>:1: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib and slated for removal in Python 3.12; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
2024-02-05 10:13:30.161136+0100 MyApp[1218:20214] Running main.py: 
/Users/pentaist/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F67E48F4-3BF3-47CC-8BBB-7D8E1661EDC0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/53C14315-F5E9-49DD-AB39-9ECB7F15C12A/MyApp.app/YourApp/main.pyc
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in 
/Users/pentaist/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F67E48F4-3BF3-47CC-8BBB-7D8E1661EDC0/data/Containers/Data/Application/834ABCDC-1C80-4834-B36E-E88150B81DE2/Documents/.kivy/logs/kivy_24-02-05_0.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.2.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at 
"/Users/pentaist/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F67E48F4-3BF3-47CC-8BBB-7D8E1661EDC0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/53C14315-F5E9-49DD-AB39-9ECB7F15C12A/MyApp.app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.10.10 (main, Feb  2 2024, 15:34:19) [Clang 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at 
"/Users/pentaist/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F67E48F4-3BF3-47CC-8BBB-7D8E1661EDC0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/53C14315-F5E9-49DD-AB39-9ECB7F15C12A/MyApp.app/MyApp"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 190 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_imageio, img_tex, img_sdl2 (img_dds, img_ffpyplayer, img_pil ignored)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
2024-02-05 10:13:31.567060+0100 MyApp[1218:20214] You need UIApplicationSupportsIndirectInputEvents in your Info.plist for mouse support
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 2.0 APPLE-20.0.39'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Apple Inc.'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Apple Software Renderer'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 0
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.00'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <4096>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <8>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [KivyMD      ] 1.2.0, git-Unknown, 2024-02-01 (installed at 
"/Users/pentaist/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F67E48F4-3BF3-47CC-8BBB-7D8E1661EDC0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/53C14315-F5E9-49DD-AB39-9ECB7F15C12A/MyApp.app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kivymd/__init__.py")
[WARNING] [KivyMD      ] Version 1.2.0 is deprecated and is no longer supported. Use KivyMD version 2.0.0 from the master branch (pip install https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
Got dlopen error on Foundation: dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Foundation, 0x0001): tried: 
'/Users/pentaist/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dunafhbudoujmgcvxgnnlyxsmztr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Foundation' (errno=2), 
'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Foundation' 
(errno=2), '/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Foundation' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), 
'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Foundation' 
(errno=2), '/Users/pentaist/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dunafhbudoujmgcvxgnnlyxsmztr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation' (errno=2), 
'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation' 
(errno=2), '/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), 
'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation' 
(errno=2)
Got fallback dlopen error on Foundation: dlopen(/Groups/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Foundation, 0x0001): tried: 
'/Users/pentaist/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dunafhbudoujmgcvxgnnlyxsmztr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Foundation' (errno=2), 
'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/Groups/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Foundation' 
(errno=2), '/Groups/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Foundation' (errno=2), 
'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Foundation' 
(errno=2)
[INFO   ] [Clipboard   ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Camera      ] Provider: avfoundation
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/pentaist/Desktop/build/MyApp-ios/YourApp/main.py", line 21, in <module>
   File "/Users/pentaist/Desktop/build/MyApp-ios/YourApp/scanner.py", line 16, in <module>
   File 
"/Users/pentaist/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F67E48F4-3BF3-47CC-8BBB-7D8E1661EDC0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/53C14315-F5E9-49DD-AB39-9ECB7F15C12A/MyApp.app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyzbar/pyzbar.py", 
line 7, in <module>
     from .wrapper import (
   File 
"/Users/pentaist/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F67E48F4-3BF3-47CC-8BBB-7D8E1661EDC0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/53C14315-F5E9-49DD-AB39-9ECB7F15C12A/MyApp.app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyzbar/wrapper.py", 
line 151, in <module>
     zbar_version = zbar_function(
   File 
"/Users/pentaist/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F67E48F4-3BF3-47CC-8BBB-7D8E1661EDC0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/53C14315-F5E9-49DD-AB39-9ECB7F15C12A/MyApp.app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyzbar/wrapper.py", 
line 148, in zbar_function
     return prototype((fname, load_libzbar()))
   File 
"/Users/pentaist/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F67E48F4-3BF3-47CC-8BBB-7D8E1661EDC0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/53C14315-F5E9-49DD-AB39-9ECB7F15C12A/MyApp.app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyzbar/wrapper.py", 
line 127, in load_libzbar
     libzbar, dependencies = zbar_library.load()
   File 
"/Users/pentaist/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F67E48F4-3BF3-47CC-8BBB-7D8E1661EDC0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/53C14315-F5E9-49DD-AB39-9ECB7F15C12A/MyApp.app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyzbar/zbar_library.py", 
line 63, in load
     path = find_library('zbar')
   File 
"/Users/pentaist/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F67E48F4-3BF3-47CC-8BBB-7D8E1661EDC0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/53C14315-F5E9-49DD-AB39-9ECB7F15C12A/MyApp.app/lib/python310.zip/ctypes/util.py", 
line 329, in find_library
   File 
"/Users/pentaist/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F67E48F4-3BF3-47CC-8BBB-7D8E1661EDC0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/53C14315-F5E9-49DD-AB39-9ECB7F15C12A/MyApp.app/lib/python310.zip/ctypes/util.py", 
line 289, in _findSoname_ldconfig
 AttributeError: module 'subprocess' has no attribute 'Popen'
2024-02-05 10:13:33.806314+0100 MyApp[1218:20214] Application quit abnormally!
2024-02-05 10:13:33.883899+0100 MyApp[1218:20214] Leaving
```

Python version (MacOS) : 3.11.7

Python version (toolchain) : 3.10.10

MacOS : Monterey 12.7.3

Xcode version : 14.2 (14C18)

main.py line 21 : from scanner import BarcodeScannerScreen

scanner.py line 16 : from pyzbar import decode

i have installed pyzbar with : toolchain pip install pyzbar

i have build zbar with : toolchain build libzbar